# .NET MVC 3 Deployment package missing references

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3, deployment

In an ASP.NET MVC3 project I have a structure like this:

```
Core.csproj
 -> 3rdparty1.dll
    -> 3rdpartyreference.dll
 -> 3rdparty2.dll

Web.csproj
 -> core.dll
```

I'm using the Build Deployment Package feature in VS2010. When I build, there are some references missing in the final bin directory. It only contains the web.dll, core.dll, 3rdparty1.dll and 3rdparty2.dll but is missing the 3rdpartyreference.dll.

How can I force the Deployment functionality to copy all the necessary references? (without manually creating a specific "copy something.dll" instruction in the afterbuild in the csproj)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The MSBuild tasks involved in the deployment package and publish features of VS 2010 fail to pickup indirect references by where your app depends on an assembly that depends on another. Either you can copy the files manually (not recommended), or you can add an unused reference variable to your core project that points to some class in the thirdpartyreference.dll. This reference variable, even if unused, will cause VS 2010 to think you have an explicit dependency on that third party dll and copy it to the bin directory as expected.

Comment: I decided for this method because it does not require 2 physical copies to keep up to date. Are there some plans for the new vs to have a config setting for this scenario (force inclusion of all references)?

Answer (score 1):

The feature you're looking for is called "Bin deployment". In this [article](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/05/25/bin-deploying-asp-net-mvc-3.aspx) there's a step-by-step solution. Basically, you need to add deployable assemblies to your project - specific folder will show up in your project structure where you can add necessary dll files.

Comment: Not sure why this is downvoted, this is a good answer.  You might need to read down a little, but there's this: `So here’s the kicker. If you’re building a web application, and you need an assembly deployed but don’t want it referenced and don’t want it checked into the bin directory, you can simply add this folder yourself and put your own assemblies in here.`  Which is exactly what the OP is asking for.

Comment: This work ok, but it requires me to keep 2 copies of the reference. One in my own ../packages/reference.dll where I keep all external references and one in _bin_deployableAssemblies. Is there a nice way to only reference in the second directory, not physically copy?

Comment: Try adding as a link. Right click -> Add -> Existing item.. -> select .dll and click arrow on the right of the "Add" text on the button -> As link