# EntityFramework.SqlServer not deployed in web publish

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, visual-studio-2012, ef-code-first

Noticed this odd thing going on, perhaps it's a bug but I might be missing something myself.

Suppose you have a solution with two projects: one is a MVC3 project, another is a class library for data access (Entity Framework model classes, data context and such).

The class library references `EntityFramework` (EF6) and `EntityFramework.SqlServer` libraries.

And the MVC project references this class library `DAL`. The `DAL` library may be used by some other code outside of the application, hence to decouple it from the web project.

Anyway, it appears that upon publishing the MVC3 project, the process misses copying the `EntityFramework.SqlServer` assembly to the publish/bin directory. However, it **does** publish base `EntityFramework` dll along with other libraries and the class library itself.

Is there a way to get the publisher to publish the required SqlServer driver as well?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Alright, so after some additional Google-fu it appears that a workaround is to create some reference to that missing assembly, even if the code is unused.

[.NET MVC 3 Deployment package missing references](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9846063/net-mvc-3-deployment-package-missing-references)

And the workaround I used is add simple test line in the constructor of the data context:

```
bool instanceExists = System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.Instance != null;
```

Comment: Do you mean in the Content.tt file?  Doesn't that get overwritten anytime you make a change?

Comment: I'm not sure why this is happening but I just created an internal class and put this statement in the constructor and it fixed the problem.

Comment: @RichC, no this is not related to TTs. I should add that this is a fix to Code-first only

Comment: Wow.  This works.  How does this even work?  Confusion! - not just in code first but in design first too

Comment: Oh I see now, all this does is force VS to copy the dll to the applicaitons bin directory.  Is there another way to do that without code?

Comment: Rather than adding it to the model context (we use quite a few tiny contexts rather than one big one), I added this line to my repository base class constructor. Worked like a charm too!

Answer (score 4):

I had the same situation. I installed EF to my web project via NuGet (I still don't use it there, just referenced to libraries) and it solve my issue.

Moreover, I can't reproduce this situation for other solution - I created new web project and referenced new lib - but deployment works.

Answer (score 1):

Add entity framework package in your package file of your project