# Why do I have to reference EF in my UI project?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Isn't there a more graceful way to have Entity Framework deployed with your UI project (specifically the sql server driver for EF: EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll) deployed with your asp.net project than having to add reference to EF via NuGet in your UI project?

In this stack overflow question, the answer posted is to make an unneeded line of code in my asp.net project just to get the dependent file to copy over when my asp.net app is deployed:

[stack overflow article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20499148/entityframework-sqlserver-not-deployed-in-web-publishework-sqlserver-not-deployed-in-web-publish)

I don't think I should have to add unused code in order to deploy a dependency.
Nor should I have to add a reference to EF in my UI project.

I understand that the EF file (EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll) is injected at run time into entity framework.
Yes - my  asp.net project is configured correctly - it runs great if it has a nuget reference to EF or the dll EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll.

But:
I don't want to add a reference to entity framework using nuget to my asp.net mvc project just to deploy this file.
I don't want to add a reference to the file, which is in my DAL project bin folder, that would be very brittle.
I could add a post build event to the asp.net mvc project, but that seems brittle too.

In MSTest projects we can add a [DeploymentItem ...] attribute to deploy these types of dependencies.  Is there an equivalent in asp.net, perhaps something you can put in the web.config.

I would think that if I could configure in the web.config to reference the sql provider used by entity framework:

```
<entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="v11.0" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
```

That you could also configure the dll to deploy too!

2/13 Edit

I am using visual studio 2013 and EF 6.

A couple of people have asked why I care and why I don't just use NuGet to manage this and add the entity framework reference to my UI project using NuGet.

2 Reasons:

1. My UI should not have to know anything about what my ORM is!  And should not need a project reference to it in my UI project.
2. More importantly, I manage a team of developers with varying skill levels, onshore and off shore.  I don't want one of them to accidentally use an EF class in the UI.  Having a reference to EF in the UI project makes it all to easy to have VS or Resharper slip in a "using System.Data.Entity;" and off you go using your ORM in your UI project.

Comment: Why can you not just add this as a project reference? What is wrong with NuGet?

Comment: I asked a closely related question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26926814/my-web-config-references-an-assembly-used-by-a-dependent-dll-library-any-way-ar?noredirect=1#comment42400392_26926814, and can't believe the answer is  supposed to be to install your dependent assemblies into the UI project. I'm no OO expert, but...

Comment: I was wondering the same thing, but for NHibernate and its dependencies as well.

Answer (score 5):

Explanation of issue(s) with EF configuration in multi project solution is here:
[EntityFramework.SqlServer (or other providers) not being copied locally](https://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/2352)
It perfect explain me the reasons, but I found better workaround:
I have a solution with UI project and DAL project.
To **not** reference EF dll's in UI project I have done:.
1) removed it from UI project references.
2) add post-build event to UI project:

```
if $(ConfigurationName) == Debug (
copy $(SolutionDir)\DBWrapper\Bin\Debug\EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll $(SolutionDir)\IrregularVerbs\Bin\Debug\
)
else if $(ConfigurationName) == Release (
copy $(SolutionDir)\DBWrapper\Bin\Release\EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll $(SolutionDir)\IrregularVerbs\Bin\Release\
)
```

the "(" char must be in the same line as "if" - in other way you get error:
*Error  2   The command "..." exited with code 255.*

Comment: This should be marked as answer. As stated on the page you provided the problem is that the required dll's are not copied locally. This can easily be fixed by adding this line of code anywhere in the DAL: 'var ensureDLLIsCopied = System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.Instance;'

Answer (score 1):

I have encountered the same problem and found the solution.

1. Remove EF references in the UI layer.
2. Remove EF references in the web.config
3. Just make sure to define the connection string

```html
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="PlayData" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLExpress;Initial Catalog=PlayHarder;Integrated Security=SSPI;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
```

There! No more reference to EF in the UI layer, and the web page will still run. Use only EF in the data layer via repositories and unit of work pattern.

To summarize: Just do NOT install or nuget-install EntityFramework in the UI layer and it will work just fine.

Comment: I know this answer/post is a bit old, but I'm encountering the excatly same issue here. I'm having a WebAPI host project (startup project) which use a DataLayer project (which has the EF), but when I'm trying to perform any actions through my Repository, I'm getting following message: "No Entity Framework provider found for the ADO.NET provider with invariant name 'System.Data.SqlClient'. Make sure the provider is registered in the 'entityFramework' section of the application config file. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=260882 for more information." Any idea of what went wrong?

Comment: In EF 6 you need to add something in the config file. Please see. http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468

Comment: I didn't find anything in there that could solve the issue. The problem is my startup project doesn't contain EF, but is dependent on a DataProject that has the app.config with EF specific details. So somehow my startup project should be able to tell the DataProject to use it own app.config instead of the host one??

Answer (score 0):

What version of EF are you using?  I have the same exact setup as you are describing... MVC proj + EF DAL proj based on EF5.  I checked the references on both projects, and neither of them refer to EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll. Both only reference EntityFramwork.dll.

Regardless, I get the basic pain point you are describing about referencing/publish dependencies. However, unlike you, I have been content to let NuGet do the work, and I don't mind that.

I just Right-Click on the Solution, and click "Manage NuGet Packages for Solution..." and then I choose the Installed packages node in the left pane, scroll to Entity Framework and click on it, then click Manage button and check it to apply to the MVC project and the DAL project.

Comment: Thank you for the thoughtful reply Matt.
I made an edit to my question above answering some of your questions.   I too am using the Manage NuGet Packages - adding EF as a reference in the UI project is currently how I have the project setup so that it will run.  Your right, I may just not have to care about it, although it makes me nervous because of my reason 2 above.

Answer (score 0):

Your reasoning is somewhat moot, but I can help clarify.

If you want to limit exposure to your EF context, then expose an interface via a unit-of-work/repository pattern.  Create an abstraction layer on top of your EF implementation that gets injected via some DI construct like Ninject or Autofac.

Either way, the only way developers won't use your EF context is to be disciplined developers.  Code reviews will help alleviate people doing dumb stuff.

Comment: Hi.  I have a repository and unit of work in a separate project which does have a reference to EF, with DTO's being passed back to the UI controllers.  EF is totally abstracted away. But I still need a reference to EF in the UI project so that EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll  will get picked up with the build in Visual Studio and deployed.   Again - UI should not need to know about EF.

Answer (score 0):

Add this code to let visual studio understand you are using entityframework.sqlserver in code.
EveryThing will become good after entering this  code to your project with EF refrence.

```
public abstract class dummy: DbContext
{
     static dummy()  
     {
          var dummyvariable= 
                System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.Instance;
     }
}
```