# My web.config references an assembly used by a dependent DLL library. Any way around this?

Tags: .net, web-config, app-config

Here is my concrete example.

I have written a dll which uses EntityFramework to talk to a database and do some work. Originally, the front end was a console application, but there is now an additional requirement for a web front end as well. 
From what I've read, the 'top-most' application (web app or console app) should store all the configuration, even the configuration which is needed only by the dll itself.

(I will use the web app as my example from now one, but it applies to the console app as well)

To get the web app working, I have moved the connection string and other settings from the dll library's app.config into my web.config.

When I run my web app, I get the following error

```
The Entity Framework provider type 'System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer' registered in the application config file for the ADO.NET provider with invariant name 'System.Data.SqlClient' could not be loaded
```

This appears to be due to the fact that in my web.config, the connection string refers to Entity Framework, and there are other EntityFramework references in there too - all of which are required by the DLL library.

One workaround is simply use NuGet to install EntityFramework into my web app. It all works, but seems very wrong - creating an unnecessary dependency.

Is there another way?

Can I untangle the web.config and place the EntityFramework stuff in the dll's app.config, whilst leaving the basic sql server connection string info in the web.config? If so, how - it's resembles spaghetti!

If this is possible, are there any guides out there?

Comment: I always have the detail in all my web.config/app.config. EG, I have the same entry in my UI layer and my DAL layer. In some cases, I even just link the file (where possible)

Comment: So your UI layer must have various dependencies installed (such as EF), even though they do not use it. Seems odd to have to install loads of stuff just to keep the web.config happy.

Comment: That is correct - sadly, I can't say it's the *right* thing, it feels counter-intuitive (some how wrong), but it is the way I do it! After doing it a few times and realising it works fine, and no real overhead (in my projects at least) I didn't bother to give it any more thought! Although it's usually only the EF dependency

Comment: This may be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21746230/why-do-i-have-to-reference-ef-in-my-ui-project

Comment: @Dave the linked question is closely related. Mine is geared towards the config files, his is more on deployment, but the overall issue is the same. The answers, disappointingly, are "just install EF to your UI using NuGet". Not what I was hoping for :(

Comment: Actually, I never do it that way (using NuGet or similar). I look at my reference to EF in the DAL. I then see what DLL it is referencing. Then I copy the link to the file, and browse for it for my UI. I then paste! :)