# EntityFramework.SqlServer not deploying

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I've seen various posts and workarounds regarding EF6 and EntityFramework.SqlServer not deploying to the bin. Here's one of a few variants: [EntityFramework.SqlServer not deployed in web publish](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20499148/entityframework-sqlserver-not-deployed-in-web-publish)

My question is if we have A with a dependency on B, and B has dependencies on EntityFramework and EntityFramework.SqlServer, why does the build only include EntityFramework in the final bin?

And isn't this really a Microsoft issue about either deployment of references or the EF 6 nuget 6 package? As opposed to working around it with various techniques that some report are faulty in certain instances.